# Different return type for query in Hibernate when changing group by

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have a method that runs a NativeQuery with resultSetMapping in Hibernate. It selects some columns (always the same columns), does some filtering and grouping and returns the result using a Query.getResultList().

This is the ResultSetMapping

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "MonthlySaleMapping", classes = @ConstructorResult(targetClass = MonthlySalesProjection.class, columns = {
    @ColumnResult(name = "segment"),
    @ColumnResult(name = "businessArea"),
    @ColumnResult(name = "customerId"),
    @ColumnResult(name = "customerGroupId"),
    @ColumnResult(name = "category"),
    @ColumnResult(name = "manufacturer"),
    @ColumnResult(name = "organizationNumber"),
    @ColumnResult(name = "year"),
    @ColumnResult(name = "monthOfYear"),
    @ColumnResult(name = "totalSales"),
    @ColumnResult(name = "totalVAT"),
    @ColumnResult(name = "tb"),
    @ColumnResult(name = "quantity")
```

}))

And this is the constructor

```
public MonthlySalesProjection(String segment, String businessArea, int customerId, int customerGroupId, String category, String manufacturer, String organizationNumber, int year, int monthOfYear, BigDecimal totalSales, BigDecimal totalVAT, BigDecimal tb, BigDecimal quantity)
```

The user has the possibility to set the group by and there lies the problem. For all variants of group by the user can do the result for year and monthOfYear (which both are int throughout the code) are returned with the the IntegerType, except for when grouping on customerId and customerId only. Then the type of those two columns are returned as BigIntegerType. I have tried setting type=int.class on my ColumnResult, but it did not help.

- Database: Mysql 8.0.26
- Connector: mysql-connector-java:8.0.26
- Hibernate:  hibernate-core:5.4.31.Final
- Java: OpenJDK 11.0.12

Does anyone know why I get different types in my SQLResultSetMapping depending on the group by?

Comment: I have now changed the constructor parameters for year and monthOfYear to Number and that seems to work, but I still have no idea as to why it returns different types depending on my group by

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that Oracle or the JDBC driver simply reports a different column type based on some query planner related difference. It's always best to set the types explicitly though to avoid such issues.

Comment: Seems reasonable. But how do you set the type? As stated I have tried type=int.class in the @ColumnResult, but it didn't make any difference

Comment: Your approach to using `Number` sounds good to me.